# I'm installing cortex and am receiving a python 'configparser' error when running the main file

Tags: python

I've cloned the [cortex](https://github.com/GGLucas/cortex) repo and change the python path in the main file from:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

to

`#!/usr/bin/python2.7`

Which is what I'm running.

However, on running the application I get the below

```
cortex$ ./cortex pirateparty
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./cortex", line 10, in <module>
from configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

Re-reading the above, I suspect I need to install python 3. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install configparser library which you probably dont have in your other python enviorment, run:

```
pip install configparser
```

Comment: that did help however I found that following that fix I was still getting similar errors. I fixed these by doing `homebrew install python3` and changing the hash bang line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. All done. Thanks for the help.